# Most efficient way to set style using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

What is the most efficient way to set multiple styling on elements in javascript?

```
for (i=0;i<=lastSelector;i++) {
var e = mySelector[i],
v = 'opacity 1s';
e.style.WebkitTransition = v;
e.style.MozTransition = v;
e.style.OTransition = v;
e.style.MsTransition = v;
e.style.transition = v;
e.style.opacity = 0;
};
```

Comment: If `v` is static, I would use a class and only add the class to the element.

Comment: FelixKling, good point! In this case I will not have acess to CSS files :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty much that, you could use a stacked assignment:

```
for (i=0;i<=lastSelector;i++) {
  var e = mySelector[i];
  e.style.WebkitTransition =
    e.style.MozTransition =
      e.style.OTransition =
        e.style.MsTransition =
          e.style.transition =
            'opacity 1s';
  e.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

Since there are several of these properties where we have vendor-specific versions, you might consider a reusable function that does this, e.g.:

```
function setMultiVendorProp(style, propName, value) {
    // Set the non-vendor version
    style[propName] = value;

    // Make first char capped
    propName = propName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + propName.substring(1);

    // Set vendor versions
    style["Webkit" + propName] = value;
    style["Moz" + propName] = value;
    style["O" + propName] = value;
    style["Ms" + propName] = value;

    // Done
    return value;
}
```

Or using the dashed style instead, since we're already using strings rather than identifiers:

```
function setMultiVendorProp(style, propName, value) {
    // Set the non-vendor version
    style[propName] = value;

    // Set vendor versions
    style["-webkit-" + propName] = value;
    style["-moz-" + propName] = value;
    style["-o-" + propName] = value;
    style["-ms-" + propName] = value;

    // Done
    return value;
}
```

Then:

```
for (i=0;i<=lastSelector;i++) {
  var e = mySelector[i];
  setMultiVendorProp(e.style, "transition", "opacity 1s");
  e.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

---

Side notes:

- There's no `;` after the closing `}` in a `for` statement.
- `var` anywhere in a function is **function-wide**, so declaring `var` within non-function blocks inside the function is (slightly) misleading to the reader of the code; details: [*Poor, misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

Comment: That was something new for me!

Comment: @Hakan: A stacked assignment? Yeah, it's pretty useful. It's a consequence of the fact that the expression `b = c` has a value (the value of the expression is the value of `c`), so in `a = b = c`, first the `b = c` expression is evaluated, and then `a = (value of result)` is evaluated. Note that the value of the far right-hand side is only taken *once*, so for instance `a = b = func();` only calls `func` **once**, and its return value is assigned to `b`, then the value of that assignment expression is assigned to `a`. Details: [Spec section 11.13.1](http://es5.github.com/#x11.13.1).

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
var i,
    es,
    v = 'opacity 1s';
for (i=0;i<=lastSelector;i++) {
    es = mySelector[i].style;

    es.WebkitTransition = v;
    es.MozTransition = v;
    es.OTransition = v;
    es.MsTransition = v;
    es.transition = v;
    es.opacity = 0;
};
```

There's no need to set `v = 'opacity 1s'` every time you go through the loop, just set it once before the loop. And as long as we're moving the declaration of `v` note that JS only has function scope so declaring variables in a loop doesn't actually limit their scope to that loop.

Comment: Of Course nnnnnn, missed that in my example... Is it necessary to declare "i"?

Comment: Any variable that you don't explicitly declare with `var` will become a global variable. This can cause hard-to-find bugs, e.g., if inside your for loop you called a function that used `i` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in a function:

```
function setStyles(styles, element, value)
{
    for(var i=0,l=styles.length;i<l;i++)
        {
            if(p in element.style)
                element.style[p] = value;
        }
    };
}
```

So you can call:

```
var s = ['WebkitTransition','MozTransition','OTransition','MsTransition','transition'];
for (i=0;i<=lastSelector;i++) {
    var e = mySelector[i],
    v = 'opacity 1s';
    setStyles(s,e,v);
    e.style.opacity = 0;
};
```